# PySpark Pytest - parametrize function name in unit tests

Tags: dataframe, unit-testing, pyspark, pytest, python-decorators

The question regards parametrization of PyTest and DataFrame custom functions applied using decorators. Let's assume, there are some columns: `col_1`, `col_2` and some methods `func_1`, `func_2` and we want to parametrize a test to ran a `func_1` on the `col_1`, `func_2` on the `col_2`, and so on...

Is it possible to parametrize the function name (similar to `column_name` parameter) that we want to execute in Unit Test ?

```py
DataFrame.custom = property(custom)

class TestExtractor():

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "column_name",
        [
            'col1',
            'col2'
        ]
    )
    def test_col(self, spark, df, column_name):

        # ACT
        df_res = df \
                .custom.func_1() \  # but it is enought to execute func_1() for col_1
                .custom.func_2() \  # but it is enought to execute func_2() for col_2
                .select(column_name)
        ....
```